# Has term pseudo-logarithmic standard meaning?

Tags: time-complexity, pseudo-polynomial

Whenever an algorithm has polynomial complexity, but exponential over the encoding of the input, it is said to be pseudo-polynomial.

What about logarithmic complexity? Wouldn't be wrong to refer to such algorithms as pseudo-polynomial (as often happens)?
Shouldn't I instead refer to them as pseudo-logarithmic algorithms?

It seems to me that this latter kind of algorithms are way more efficient and worth to be destinquished. Am I right?

Comment: You're free to use any term you want, as long as you define it. In some cases a concept already has a name, and in such cases, it's usually a good idea to use it.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant something else. I rephrased my question.